# Using cuModuleLoad to get current Module from ELF binary (from argv[0])

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

Situation:
I am trying to use cuModuleLoad to load the current binary's (ELF) embedded cubin (and PTX), but it keep erroring out with error code 200. My question is, if the cubin is embedded into the final binary, why can't I use cuModuleLoad to dynamically load ones self? It works when the I compile a separate fatbinary, but not when I load a separate PTX module, and of course when I try to load the final binary (a.out). I have a few reasons why I want to load the current executable that I will forgo to not go off topic. I am also looking for a workaround that maintains a single file without using utility tools (or system calls).

In Linux:

```
#include "cuda.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using clock_value_t = long long;

__device__ void test(  )
{
  printf("Testing... : \n");
}

__device__ void sleep(clock_value_t sleep_cycles)
{
    clock_value_t start = clock64();
    clock_value_t cycles_elapsed;
    do { cycles_elapsed = clock64() - start; }
    while (cycles_elapsed < sleep_cycles);
}

extern "C" __global__ void hello_world(  )
{
  printf("Hello World from Device\n");
  sleep( 1e9 );
  test();
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

  std::cout << argv[0] << std::endl;

  // Initialize input vectors    ...
  //Initialize
  cuInit(0);
  // Get number of devices supporting CUDA
  int deviceCount = 0;
  cuDeviceGetCount(&deviceCount);

  if (deviceCount == 0)
  {
    printf("There is no device supporting CUDA.\n");
    exit (0);
  }
  else std::cout << "Number of device is "<< deviceCount << std::endl;

  // Get handle for device 0
  CUdevice cuDevice;
  cuDeviceGet(&cuDevice, 0);
  // Create context
  CUcontext cuContext;
  int ret = cuCtxCreate(&cuContext, 0, cuDevice);

  if( ret != CUDA_SUCCESS )
          std::cout << "Could not create context on device 0" << std::endl;

  // Create module from binary file
  CUmodule cuModule;

  ret = cuModuleLoad(&cuModule, argv[0]); // <---errors HERE
  
  if( ret != CUDA_SUCCESS )
  {
    std::cout << "Failed to load self fatbin : " << argv[0] << " : " << ret<< std::endl;
    return -1;
  }
}
```

I would be bummed if If I have to use a separate file, or a utility to extract the cubins or PTXs dynamically. Anyways- thank you guys for your insight ahead of time.

Comment: "The file should be a cubin file as output by nvcc, or a PTX file either as output by nvcc or handwritten, or a fatbin file as output by nvcc from toolchain 4.0 or later." -- I don't see host executables or elf files listed. Do you?

Comment: Correct- I understand the documentation. I was wondering if their is a workaround, or a side door since the binary has it embedded. All the pieces to the puzzle are there for it to possibly work if implemented, if not, I wonder why it wouldn't work.

Comment: There isn't. The driver API knows nothing about the runtime API, and the runtime API doesn't work the way you want to either. Come to think of it, there isn't even this sort of functionality exposed in the standard host elf implementation. You can't magically delay load a custom section of an elf executable and bootstrap either. If you want runtime API like functionality then use the runtime API!

Comment: How about with cuModuleLoadData? It says in Windows I can use FindResource for cubin's incorporated into an executable resources. I'm not familiar with FindResource, but seems it does what I would like in an indirect way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution. In a nutshell :

1. fopen( argv[0] )
2. mmap ( file )
3. Read the ELF headers and find the ".nv_fatbin" section
4. Parse the ".nv_fatbin" aligning to byte sequence "50 ed 55 ba 01 00 10 00"
5. Find the cubin related to the global method you want to cuModuleGetFunction
6. Call cuModuleLoadFatBinary with a base address of the .nv_fatbin + specific cubin offset.
7. Get the function using cuModuleGetFunction
8. Finally call cuLaunchKernel

See sloppy code below for reference:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  std::cout << "Hello World from Host" << std::endl;
  std::cout << argv[0] << std::endl;
  void * start_ptr =NULL;
  struct stat sb;
  size_t sz =0;

  //read_elf_header( argv[0] );
  // Either Elf64_Ehdr or Elf32_Ehdr depending on architecture.
  ElfW(Ehdr) elf_header;
  ElfW(Shdr) header;

  std::cout << "opening elf file" << std::endl;
  FILE* file = fopen(argv[0], "rb");

  int fd = fileno( file );

  if (fd < 0)
  {
    printf("Could not open file for memory mapping, fd = %i\n", errno);
    exit(1);
  }

  std::cout << "getting file size" << std::endl;
  if (fstat(fd, &sb) == -1)          // To obtain file size
    printf("Could not find fstat");
  sz = sb.st_size;

  std::cout << "Mapping file to memory : " << sz << std::endl;
  start_ptr = mmap(NULL, sz, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);

  //check if valid elf
  bool b = elf_is_elf64( file );
  fseek( file, 0, SEEK_SET );
  std::cout << "is ELF file : " << b << std::endl;
  if( b)
  {
    std::cout << "Found valid ELF file" << std::endl;
    //get ELF_Header
    b = elf64_get_elf_header(file, &elf_header);
    fseek( file, 0, SEEK_SET );

    if( b )
    {
      std::cout << "-Found valid ELF Header" << std::endl;
      b = elf64_get_section_header_by_name(file, (const Elf64_Ehdr *) &elf_header, ".nv_fatbin", &header);
      fseek( file, 0, SEEK_SET );

      if( b )
      {
        std::cout << "Found fatbin section" << std::endl;
        cuInit(0);
        // Get number of devices supporting CUDA
        int deviceCount = 0;
        cuDeviceGetCount(&deviceCount);

        if (deviceCount == 0)
        {
          printf("There is no device supporting CUDA.\n");
          exit (0);
        }
        else std::cout << "Number of device is "<< deviceCount << std::endl;

        // Get handle for device 0
        CUdevice cuDevice;
        cuDeviceGet(&cuDevice, 0);
        // Create context
        CUcontext cuContext;
        int ret = cuCtxCreate(&cuContext, 0, cuDevice);
        if( ret != CUDA_SUCCESS )
          std::cout << "Could not create context on device 0" << std::endl;
        // Create module from binary file
        CUmodule cuModule;
        std::cout << "sh_addr = " <<  header.sh_addr << std::endl;
        unsigned long long offset = header.sh_addr;
        
        unsigned long long cuOffset = _find_cubin_offset( header, start_ptr, offset, "_Z11hello_worldv");

        const void * fatbin = &((unsigned char *) start_ptr)[cuOffset];
        
        std:: cout << "fat bin = " << fatbin << std::endl;

        ret = cuModuleLoadFatBinary(&cuModule, fatbin );

        if( ret != CUDA_SUCCESS )
        {
          std::cout << "Failed to load self fatbin : " << argv[0] << " : " << ret<< std::endl;
        }

        CUfunction khw;
        //ret = cuModuleGetFunction(&khw, cuModule, "hello_world");
        ret = cuModuleGetFunction(&khw, cuModule, "_Z11hello_worldv");
        if( ret != CUDA_SUCCESS )
        {
          std::cout << "Failed to get hello_world from " << argv[0] << " : " << ret <<  std::endl;
        }
        else ret = cuLaunchKernel(khw, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NULL, 0);

        if( ret != CUDA_SUCCESS )
        {
          std::cout << "Failed to launch : hello_world "  << std::endl;
        }

        ret = cuModuleUnload(cuModule);

        if( ret != CUDA_SUCCESS )
        {
          std::cout << "Failed to unload self fatbin : " << argv[0] << std::endl;
          return -1;
        }

        if (cudaDeviceSynchronize() != cudaSuccess)
        {
          printf ("Cuda call failed\n");
        }

        //unmap sutff
        munmap(start_ptr, sz);
        return 0;
      }
    }

  }

  fclose(file);

  return 0;
```